# Optimise query Where Exists () or Exists()

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am trying to understand why my query performance is bad for this specific query.

The query is generated by Entity Framework from a LINQ Statement, and I have found the following so far.

The query is basically

```
Select Count(*) From Table
Where Exists (A) or Exists(B)
```

I do think I have the proper indexes made already. I tried the tuning tool on SQL Sserver and it did not give me any recommendations.

However if I execute either of the two statements within exists, they are instant. If I do any of the following two statements they are both instant also

```
Select Count(*) From Table
Where Exists (A)
```

and

```
Select Count(*) From Table
Where Exists(B)
```

So somehow that where Exists(A) or Exists(B) makes it super slow. Taking 2min to return a count of 50.000.

The full query is as below, and I am looking to understand or maybe simply restructure the query somehow so the query optimiser is able to optimise it better, as I also have to change the .NET LINQ query to reflect it after.

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)  FROM [dbo].[TournamentParticipants] AS [t]
WHERE EXISTS 
( --This part is checking if the record has been shared with the specific identity
        SELECT 1      
        FROM [dbo].[Permissions] AS [p1]      
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[RecordShares] AS [r] ON [p1].[Id] = [r].[PermissionId]      
        WHERE [r].[Identity] =  'A0461D73-E979-449C-B24F-A3B3D6711D61' AND [r].[EntityName] = 'TournamentParticipants' AND [r].[RecordId] = [t].[Id] AND [p1].[Name] = 'TournamentParticipantsRead' 
)  
OR EXISTS 
( -- This part will do RBAC checking if the identity has a permission itself, or is part of group that has its permission      
    SELECT 1      
    FROM (          
        SELECT [p].[Name]          
        FROM [dbo].[Permissions] AS [p]          
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityRolePermissions] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[PermissionId]          
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityRoleAssignments] AS [s0] ON [s].[SecurityRoleId] = [s0].[SecurityRoleId]          
        INNER JOIN (              
            SELECT [s1].[Id], [s1].[CreatedById], [s1].[CreatedOn], [s1].[ModifiedById], [s1].[ModifiedOn], [s1].[Name], [s1].[OwnerId], [s1].[RowVersion], [s1].[ExternalId], [s1].[IsBusinessUnit], [s2].[Id] AS [Id0], [s2].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById0], [s2].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn0], [s2].[IdentityId], [s2].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById0], [s2].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn0], [s2].[OwnerId] AS [OwnerId0], [s2].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion0], [s2].[SecurityGroupId]              
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroups] AS [s1]              
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityGroupMembers] AS [s2] ON [s1].[Id] = [s2].[SecurityGroupId]              
            WHERE [s2].[IdentityId] = 'A0461D73-E979-449C-B24F-A3B3D6711D61'          
        ) AS [t1] ON [s0].[IdentityId] = [t1].[Id]          
        UNION          
        SELECT [p0].[Name]          
        FROM [dbo].[Permissions] AS [p0]          
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityRolePermissions] AS [s3] ON [p0].[Id] = [s3].[PermissionId]          
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityRoleAssignments] AS [s4] ON [s3].[SecurityRoleId] = [s4].[SecurityRoleId]          
        WHERE [s4].[IdentityId] = 'A0461D73-E979-449C-B24F-A3B3D6711D61'      
    ) AS [t0]      
    WHERE [t0].[Name] = 'TournamentParticipantsReadGlobal' OR 
    
        ([t0].[Name] = 'TournamentParticipantsRead' AND ([t].[OwnerId] = 'A0461D73-E979-449C-B24F-A3B3D6711D61'    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1          
        FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroups] AS [s5]          
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityGroupMembers] AS [s6] ON [s5].[Id] = [s6].[SecurityGroupId]          
        WHERE [s6].[IdentityId] = 'A0461D73-E979-449C-B24F-A3B3D6711D61' AND [s5].[Id] = [t].[OwnerId]))) 
        
        OR ([t0].[Name] = 'TournamentParticipantsReadBU' AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1          
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupMembers] AS [s7]          
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityGroups] AS [s8] ON [s7].[SecurityGroupId] = [s8].[Id]          
            WHERE [s7].[IdentityId] = [t].[OwnerId] AND [s8].[IsBusinessUnit] = CAST(1 AS bit) AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1              
            FROM [dbo].[SecurityGroupMembers] AS [s9]              
            WHERE [s9].[IdentityId] = 'A0461D73-E979-449C-B24F-A3B3D6711D61' AND [s9].[SecurityGroupId] = [s8].[Id])))
)
```

Comment: `OR` statements negate the possibility of doing a seek most (all?) of the time. It can't seek to a specific set of rows because even if it finds rows with one predicate, it has to do another search  for the other part of the clause, and that's not how the query optimizer works. You end up having to do index scans for all the different `OR` conditions in your query

Comment: `Where Exists (SELECT A ...) OR Exists (SELECT B ...)` is equivalent to `Where Exists (SELECT A ... UNION ALL SELECT B ...)`  which may or may not give a better plan

Comment: An another similar rearrangement could be `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT id FROM table WHERE EXISTS (A) UNION SELECT id FROM table WHERE EXISTS (B))` The UNION will have a cost not present in Martin's version, but it is an option.

Comment: You appear to also have a lot of other duplicated code. How about you show the C# that generated this, I'm sure there are efficiencies to be made.

Comment: I think you would do better to invert your logic by starting with `DECLARE @UserIdentity UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = ...`, look up all security groups for that user, and then look up all roles for that user and containing security groups. From there you can write separate queries to identify the TournamentParticipants.ID values for each access path (explicit row permission, direct ownership, indirect ownership, or other read permissions). Union these results together and join back to `TournamentParticipants` (or just count the distinct IDs) at then end. The "ReadGlobal" might warrant a separate query.

Comment: Please include the execution plan in [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) or in [Check The Plan](https://checktheplan.com/?engine=sqlserver).

Comment: Show your LINQ query and classes. Most likely you have used bad approach to check permissions.

Comment: An RBAC query is EXACTLY THE WRONG THING to try to do with an ORM's query language. LINQ isn't embedded SQL and ORMs deal with entities, not tables. To get good performance you need to fine tune the RBAC SQL query. The *correct* way to implement RBAC is with optimized views and, in SQL Server's case, table-valued UDFs, that ensure only permitted data is returned by queries. You can map entities to views. If these views are well written, they'll allow updating the underlying table.

Comment: You can also use command interceptors to combine EF's queries with RBAC filtering views or functions. On the other hand, all multi-user databases have roles that can be used to implement role security. SQL Server, Oracle and other databases even offer [row-level security mechanisms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16) that are easier to manage and faster than hand-rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of **all** EXISTS operators. Use LEFT JOIN instead, like:

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT [t].[Id])
FROM [dbo].[TournamentParticipants] AS [t]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[RecordShares] AS [r]
        ON [r].[Identity] =  'A0461D73-E979-449C-B24F-A3B3D6711D61' AND [r].[EntityName] = 'TournamentParticipants' AND [r].[RecordId] = [t].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Permissions] AS [p1]
        ON [p1].[Id] = [r].[PermissionId] AND [p1].[Name] = 'TournamentParticipantsRead'
WHERE [p1].[Id] IS NOT NULL
```

You just need to add the joins for your second condition like this, and at the end you should have:

```
WHERE [p1].[Id] IS NOT NULL OR [SomethingElse] IS NOT NULL
```

After that you can look at the execution plan (probably it will be more optimal at this stage), and if you see any Nested Loops there then you can look to add corresponding indexes on the fields used in joins.